# create an array with new objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'd like to create new objects from the values of "value1","value2" and "value3"

```
 myArray = [{fruit: "apple", value1: 3, value2:2, value1 :1}]
```

The result I'd like is

```
myNewArray = [ {fruit: "apple", item: "value1"},{fruit: "apple", item: "value1"},{fruit: "apple", item: "value1"},{fruit: "apple", item: "value2"},{fruit: "apple", item: "value2"},{fruit: "apple", item: "value3"}]
```

Comment: quite confusing, what you are exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please update your question and include what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the outer array with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), use object [destructuring with rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) to separate the `fruit` from the values. Get the values key/value pairs with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), and iterate them with `Array.map()`. For each value, use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to generate a new array of objects with the value as length, and the key as the `item`. [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to flatten the sub-arrays generated by each use of `Array.map`:

```js
const myArray = [{fruit: "apple", value1: 3, value2:2, value3 :1}];

const result = [].concat(...myArray.map(({ fruit, ...values }) => 
  [].concat(...Object.entries(values)
    .map(([item, length]) => Array.from({ length }, () => ({
      fruit,
      item
    })))
)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
var myArray = [{fruit: "apple", value1: 3, value2:2, value3 :1}] 

var myNewArray = []
function insertItem (ct, itemName, fruit) {
    var itemArr = [];
    for(var i=0;i< ct;i++){
        var newItem = {fruit};
        newItem['item'] = itemName;
        itemArr.push(newItem);
    }
    return itemArr;
}
myArray.forEach(function (obj) {
    myNewArray.push(...insertItem(obj.value1, 'value1', obj.fruit));
    myNewArray.push(...insertItem(obj.value2, 'value2', obj.fruit));
    myNewArray.push(...insertItem(obj.value3, 'value3', obj.fruit));
})

console.log(myNewArray);
```